# React + Google Analytics 4 no funciona. 0 Visitas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, github-pages

Quiero poner Google Analytics en una pagina en react desplegada en GH-Pages.
Mediante la libreria react-ga lo estoy intentando hacer pero no me funciona. Me pone las visitas a 0 y no se incrementan.

¿ Alguien sabe que puede estar ocurriendo ?

config.js

```
export const GA_TRACKING_CODE = "ID";
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { GA_TRACKING_CODE } from "../../config";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

ReactGA.initialize(GA_TRACKING_CODE);

const Home = () => {

useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + 
    window.location.search);
});
return (/*Mi Codigo*/);
};

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema era el codigo de track que me proporcionaba Google Analytics 4.
Codigo Necesario para React Ga es UA-XXX-X en cambio yo obtenia este codigo G-XXX

Os dejo un enlace de como crear el codigo de Google Analytics de forma correcta
https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/79268156?hl=en&msgid=79274289